# How to inspect openshift build log?

Tags: git, maven, openshift

I have an application, which is deployed to OpenShift via pushing the source code to the git repo.

I need to troubleshoot a problem, which occurs during maven build, only when it is executed on OpenShift (debugging locally is not an option).

However, I can't figure out a way to inspect maven build logs.

Comment: +1 for good an answer.

Comment: Did you mean to say "pulling" instead of "pushing"? Assuming it's an S2I build, you're pulling code from git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways to inspect the logs.

1. Using RabbitVCS Git(on Ubuntu).
   I think, the approach should work fine for other Git clients, as
   well. When I push the changes - RabbitVCS Git, prints the build log
   into the push log.
2. Instructing maven to print its log to a file.
   This can be done via pre_build action hook, by adding the following line:

   export MAVEN_ARGS="clean package -Popenshift > PATH/TO/FILE.log"

   once the build is done, the file can be accessed on the gear, essentially, via SSH.

Comment: About Maven (or Gradle) log I think it's better to put it in the $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR, in this way you can then run the command "rhc tail -a <your app>" and check all app-related logs on-fly.

Comment: I tried export MAVEN_ARGS="clean package -Popenshift > $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/build.log", but I got Unknown lifecycle phase ">".

Answer (score 3):

You can either use the 'rhc tail' command, or you can ssh into your gear and look in the ~/app-root/logs directory, specifically at your java server logs.  If you are using jenkins to build your application, then you will need to log into the jenkins server and look at the console build logs to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks so far, but is it possible to see the maven build logs? I have a very similar situation to the authors where the build by server doesn't have classes compiled, while if I were to do it locally on the folder, it would compile wel.